# Polynomial solutions to a polynomial using syzygies

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, groebner-basis, syzygies

$\newcommand\C{\mathbb C}\newcommand\syz{\operatorname{syz}} \newcommand\x{\mathbf x}\newcommand\a{\mathbf a}$Let $\a=a_1,\dots,a_m$ and $\x = x_1,\dots, x_n$ be indeterminates and consider a polynomial
$F(\a, \x) \in \C[\a,\x]$ and having a constant term $1$ with respect to the indeterminates $a_i$'s i.e. $F(\mathbf 0,\x)\equiv 1$. I want to see if I can solve for
$a_i\in \C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that $F(\a,\x)$ is identical to $0$. Let $R=\C[\x]$ and consider now the coefficients of the monomials of $F$ regarded as a polynomial in $R[\a]$, lets call them $\alpha_0,\dots, \alpha_N$ where $\alpha_0=1$ is the constant term of $F$. I can now compute the first syzygy $S:=\syz(\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_N) \subset R^{N+1}$ of these coefficients. $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module and it can be generated by say $k$ elements in $R^{N+1}$. And now comes my question...

If the ideal generated by the $0$-coordinate of these $k$ elements above (these corresponds to $\alpha_0$) is not the whole ring $R$, then is it OK to conclude that I do not have a polynomial solution for the $a_i$'s such that $F(\a,\x) \equiv 0$?

I can imagine something going wrong like for instance some of the $\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_N$ could be algebraically dependent (or even equal) but I don't think this matters here, right?

Comment: What's the syzygy of a set of elements in a ring?

Comment: If you consider linear combinations of these (finite) elements and consider the coefficients of these combinations (as tuples with entries in the ring) that make such a linear combination 0 then you get the (first) syzygy. Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_syzygy_theorem) explains it better. You can consider them as "relations" of these elements. I think [Roger's AMS exposition](https://www.ams.org/notices/200604/what-is.pdf) on syzygies is also free to download.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I think it might be helpful to understand why you believe the ideal $0$-coordinates of the first syzygy module not containing the unit should imply $F$ doesn't have a solution, as well as why algebraic dependence of the $\alpha_i$ could, and shouldn't matter

Comment: I thought the way I wrote the question gave it away. But the intuition behind the first is because we need to generate the constant term $1$ (thus the whole ring) and the second is because I just simply don't see why generating this term has anything to do with the algebraic dependence of these $\alpha_i$.

Comment: I'm just saying I don't really know how to approach the question. I'm clearly not an expert here so I don't mean to imply that you aren't giving enough detail

Comment: Not a problem at all. I should have written that anyway! Thanks.